# How do you move a raster's origin 1m east in R?

Tags: raster, r, origin-destination

I'm new to R (and coding in general).
I'm wondering if it is possible to create a copy of a raster layer that is identical, but moved over 1m to the East.

Comment: Suggestion, if this is not about RStudio per se simply delete "studio" from the question title. Please clarify if you mean a "raster package" raster (not a matrix, stars, graphics-package-raster, or other).

Comment: I've edit the title and question as per @mdsumner - "R" is the language, "RStudio" is the interface you are using with the editor window and the menus and all the bits you don't need to run the code.

Answer (score 4):

if it's a raster-package raster you can do

```
r2 <- setExtent(r, extent(xmin(r) + 1, xmax(r) + 1, ymin(r), ymax(r)))
```

But, beware that's a "use at your own risk" move because we assume `1` is one metre (it might be in degrees, or km - look at the crs), *and* that "East" is to the right in the "positive x" direction (this is wildly not true in many projections).

Print the thing out

```
print(r)
```

and compare

```
print(r2)
```

Look at the `extent: xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax` to check.